# Audacity and Microphone problem

Tags: audio-recording, audacity

I'm running the most recent versions of Ubuntu and Audacity and I have a vblog microphone installed and it works fine. Every time when I start Audacity, the settings for the microphone in Ubuntu become disabled. If I select microphone settings in Audacity, the same happens. 
I have to constantly keep the mic settings of Ubuntu open in order to re-enable and adjust the microphone.

This is rather annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Since having asked this question also on the Audacity forum, I was advised to install pulseaudio, and that fixed the problem.